# Como exibir os valores de entrada da matriz sem [' ']

Tags: python

Eu fiz uma matriz com 12 elementos que possui 4 linhas e colunas e queria que elas fossem exibidas assim sem [' '] em forma de lista, mas eu não quero que a saída seja exibida assim:

Lembrando: Deve funciona com números floats negativos e floats positivos digitados

```
Entrada:
02 04 06
08 10 12
14 16 18
20 22 24
```

```
Saída esperada:
02 04 06
08 10 12
14 16 18
20 22 24
```

```
Mas a saída está assim:
['02', '04', '06']
['08', '10', '12']
['14', '16', '18']
['20', '22', '24']
```

```
Meu código:
mt1 = input().split()
mt2 = input().split()
mt3 = input().split()
mt4 = input().split()

print (mt1)
print (mt2)
print (mt3)
print (mt4)
```

Comment: Por onde você está estudando Python? A frequência de perguntas me parece um pouco anormal.

Comment: Aleatoriamente (mas o problema maior é matriz)

Comment: Dá para fazer com dois for, dps eu vou mandar uma versão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bom, eu não recomendaria fazer assim mas posso ajudar.

```
mt1 = input().split()
mt2 = input().split()
mt3 = input().split()
mt4 = input().split() # a função split retorna uma lista, mesmo que contendo apenas um elemento

matriz = [mt1,mt2, mt3, mt4] # já que você está trabalhando com lista junte tudo numa lista apenas 

for i in range(len(matriz)): # para varrer as linhas da matriz
    for j in range(len(matriz[i])): # para varrer todos os elementos da linha ou seja as colunas.
        print (matriz[i][j], end = "\t") # printa o elemento da linha um ao lado do outro 
    print() # dá espaço para uma nova linha.
```

lembrando que essa não é a melhor solução você poderia usar uma lista encadeada, ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Desse jeito pude entender melhor, obrigado Filipe.

Answer (score 3):

Há várias formas de fazer isso, como pode ser visto nas demais respostas. Vou deixar uma solução que, ao meu ver, é bastante elegante.

Você já deve ter percebido que a função `print` pode receber diversos parâmetros, resultando em printar cada um dos parâmetros separados por um espaço.

```
print('sem', 'tempo,', 'irmão') => printa "sem tempo, irmão"
```

Através do asterísco (que é o operador de *unpack*), o Python permite usar os valores de uma lista como argumentos de uma função.

```
argumentos = ['sem', 'tempo,', 'irmão']
print(*argumentos) => printa "sem tempo, irmão"
```

Sabendo isso, você pode usar a mesma técnica no seu código.

```
print(*mt1)
print(*mt2)
print(*mt3)
print(*mt4)
```

O resultado vai ser o que você deseja.

Caso você queira colocar outro separador que não seja um espaço, basta informar no parâmetro nomeado `sep`.

```
print(*mt1, sep=' - ')
```

Leitura adicional:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print
- https://medium.com/rafaeltardivo/python-entendendo-o-uso-de-args-e-kwargs-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-m%C3%A9todos-c8c2810e9dc8

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [método `.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) de string. O uso é

```py
# STRING.join(LISTA)
# Exemplo:
print( ".".join(['192', '168', '0', '1']))
# result: 192.168.0.1
```

Mas no seu caso, apenas coloque ele nas linhas do print:

```py
mt1 = input().split()
mt2 = input().split()
mt3 = input().split()
mt4 = input().split()

print (' '.join(mt1))
print (' '.join(mt2))
print (' '.join(mt3))
print (' '.join(mt4))
```

Comment: Eu tinha visto o método **join** por auto, deu certo obrigado.

Comment: Isso funciona com números floats negativos e floats positivos?

Comment: Só funciona se for uma lista de strings. Do contrário ele retorna um erro. Você deve converter antes para string com `str(3.14)`